Why isn't OpenAI API Assistant aware of my vector store
I have an assistant configured with openai api v2 using gpt-4o. The assistant is linked to a vector store containing pdf documents. When testing the assistant in the openai playground it replies based on the content in the pdf documents. However, when setting up communication with the assistant through the OpenAI API the assistant is unaware of the linked vector store in the replies, meaning that it is not using the vector store as a source when searching for answers to questions. The assistant is manually linked to the vector store in the OpenAI Dashboard. After reading forums and documentation for days I'm still not able to figure out why this is happening. Below is my php code for this setup
$api_key = 'MY-API-KEY';
$assistant_id = 'MY-ASSISTANT-ID';

// Get the POST data
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
$user_message = isset($data['message']) ? $data['message'] : '';

// Debugging: Log incoming message
error_log("User message: " . $user_message);

// Prepare the payload for OpenAI API request
$payload = json_encode([
'model' => 'gpt-4o',
    'messages' => [
        ['role' => 'system', 'content' => 'You are connected to a vector store for enhanced responses.'],
        ['role' => 'user', 'content' => $user_message]
    ]
  ]);


// Debugging: Log payload
error_log("Payload: " . $payload);

// Initialize cURL session
$ch = curl_init();

// Set the URL and other options
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.openai.com/v1/chat/completions');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $payload);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [
'Content-Type: application/json',
'Authorization: Bearer ' . $api_key,
]);

// Execute cURL session and get the response
$response = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
$error_message = 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
error_log($error_message);
echo json_encode(['reply' => $error_message]);
exit;
}
curl_close($ch);

// Debugging: Log raw response
error_log("Raw response: " . $response);

// Decode the response
$response_data = json_decode($response, true);

// Debugging: Log decoded response
error_log("Decoded response: " . print_r($response_data, true));

// Check for errors in the response
if (isset($response_data['error'])) {
error_log("API Error: " . $response_data['error']['message']);
echo json_encode(['reply' => 'API Error: ' . $response_data['error']['message']]);
exit;
}

// Extract the assistant's reply
$assistant_reply = isset($response_data['choices'][0]['message']['content']) ? 
$response_data['choices'][0]['message']['content'] : 'No response from assistant.';

// Debugging: Log assistant reply
error_log("Assistant reply: " . $assistant_reply);

// Return the reply as JSON
echo json_encode(['reply' => $assistant_reply]);


What does "unaware" mean? Are you sure this problem is directly related to PHP? Would this work better when calling the API any other way?

Unaware in this context means that the assistant isn't using the vector store when searching for answers to questions. If there is another way that is better for calling the Assistant I would love to hear about it. Thank you.

Please add all clarification to your question by editing it

Thakn you for your advise, question is updated with more information

Per https://platform.openai.com/docs/assistants/tools/file-search/vector-stores the proper instructions to pass in your prompt should be similar to this: "You are a helpful product support assistant and you answer questions based on the files provided to you."
Meaning you should not say:
['role' => 'system', 'content' => 'You are connected to a vector store for enhanced responses.']

But should instead say:
['role' => 'system', 'content' => 'You answer questions based on the files provided to you.']

Additionally per this support thread: https://community.openai.com/t/do-names-of-vector-stores-names-help-the-assitant-retrieve-like-function-names-do/729019 an OpenAI employee noted that, "The name of the vector store isn’t sent in the model message at all, and doesn’t impact the model’s ability to retrieve. The name simply helps you find your vector store." - so you can't specifically call out the file name.
So just tell it to use "the files" instead of "the vector store".
